# Failed to minify the code from this file: node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js:74

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

This is a react project. I am getting when i try to do npm run build. Have no idea why it suddenly starts behaving this way.
I am using  react-router, react-router-dom version 6.2.1 and react-scripts version 5.0.0. So not sure what's the actual issue.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abc-app build: `node dev/scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the abc-app build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```